# How to get the LATEST value for each sellerID for each productID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

At the company where I work we buy the same products from different sellers according to who offers us the better price, and to make the purchase decisions easier I'd like a query that would tell me for each productId, what's the latest price recorded for each seller iD.

I have a table that looks something like this.

| purchaseId | productId | price | sellerId | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23 | 1 | 2021-01-13 |
| 2 | 2 | 20 | 1 | 2021-01-13 |
| 3 | 1 | 33 | 2 | 2021-01-19 |
| 4 | 3 | 55 | 2 | 2021-01-19 |
| 5 | 2 | 25 | 1 | 2021-01-23 |
| 6 | 1 | 19 | 3 | 2021-01-23 |
| 7 | 1 | 22 | 1 | 2021-01-26 |
| 8 | 2 | 29 | 2 | 2021-01-29 |

I'd like the query to return a table like this, with a column for each sellerID:

| productId | priceSellerID1 | priceSellerId2 | priceSellerId3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 33 | 19 |
| 2 | 25 | 19 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | 55 | NULL |

There are and could be more and more sellers, this is just a small example.

I want to pull this information to fill a DataGridView in a winforms app, what I thought of first was to populate the DGV with the productIds, and then, for each row pull the information with a query like this for each sellerId:

SELECT price FROM purchase_details
WHERE productId = @productID AND date = (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM purchase_details WHERE productId = @productID and sellerId = @sellerId)

This takes lot of time to fill in the dgv for just a few ids, so I know it's just not the right way, but unfortunately I can't wrap my head around a query that would gather this information efficiently.

Any information would be greatly appreciated, and if there's way I could improve the question I'd like to know too. Thanks.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Are there only ever 3 sellers? If not what happens when you have 4 sellers? 5? 50?

Comment: What does this question have to do with [tag:c#] and [tag:winforms]? Are you looking for a solution in C# which is in a winforms application?

Comment: If always the lowest offer is chosen, why not simply query the MIN(price) for each product?

Comment: The title says you want the "MIN price" but your explanation says you want the "latest price". Which one is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for Dynamic SQL with a little twist.  The subquery `src` will select the last record per `productID` and `SellerID` ordered by `date`

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) ='
Select *
 From  (
        Select top 1 with ties 
               productID
              ,Item  = concat(''priceSellerID'',sellerId)
              ,Value = price
         From #YourTable
         Order by row_number() over (partition by productID,SellerID order by date desc)
       ) src 
 Pivot (min([Value]) For [Item] in (' + stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(concat('priceSellerID',sellerId)) 
                                               From #YourTable 
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p
'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: WOW, you're answer is so surprisingly accurate, thanks a lot. Just one more thing, how would you go about reducing the specifying the query to just a few select sellerIds? As in, I could have 16 sellerIds but just want the prices to IDs 4,5 and 9 for example.

Comment: @AbrahamTellez you can add a WHERE... for example  "...From #YourTable WHERE ..."

Comment: Oh yeah, I first tried to put the WHERE clause in the SELECT part of the query and it didn't work, but in the PIVOT it gave the exact result I wanted, thanks a lot.